# Transactional Email - Difference between backend and files

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail, edit

I have a question about transactional emails

I ever modified it from backend at *System -> Transactional Email* and it works perfectly!

Just for fun, I searched into my directories and I found different places where are stored different kinds of transactional emails, eg. I've found it into:

`/app/locale/[you_language]/template/email/`

and also in:

`/app/design/frontend/[your_theme]/default/locale/[your_language]/template/email/`

They are different from the emails that I'd modified from backend
Now, I want to know why I've a lot of different places where emails are stored? why they are different from backend's emails?

Answer (score 0):

By default magento provides transaction email template for order, customer,invoice,shipment related entity.

You can find list of default email templates from **System -> Transaction email** from admin.

In above location all email are given by magento core team. This is the default functionality of email templates.

If you have required to changes in email then you have to just changes from backend as per your requirement not from core files.

So you have to modify from backend not from core files.

If you not modify core templates then default mail is send.

Comment: I Rakesh, thank you for reply... Surely I asked not well my question...So I want to know it: what's the function of the core files for transactional emails ? Also why If I try to open it ( both of paths that I show ) the content of core files is not the same of the transactional emails that I can open from backend? I hope that you can help me... If again I was not clear to explain I'll try to talk to you better! I'm waiting for your reply